# Why my property won't reflect iron-localstorage value?

Tags: polymer, local-storage, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I have a login system where I need to keee the logged in user on localstorage, and once the user logs I want to redirect him to his own page whenever he accesses the login page.

My template:

```
<iron-localstorage name="user-storage" value="{{storedUser}}"></iron-localstorage>
```

My object:

```
        static get properties() {
            return {
                storedUser: {
                    type: Object,
                    notify: true
                },
                ...
            }
        }
```

I want to do this:

```
        redirect() {
            console.log(this.storedUser);
            if(this.storedUser) {
                // Redirect user or admin to their own homescreen
                if(this.storedUser.role == 'user')
                    this.set('route.path', '/homescreen-usuario');
                else if(this.storedUser.role == 'admin')
                    this.set('route.path', '/homescreen-admin');
                else
                    this.set('route.path', '/my-view404');
            }
        }
```

But the first line always logs "undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the 'on-iron-localstorage-load-empty' and 'on-iron-localstorage-load' events to react to the storage events, or you can use an observer on your 'storedUser' property.